# How to run jenkins pipeline jobs in parallel which call the same downstream job?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am a beginner to jenkins and making groovy scripts for pipelines, I want to trigger a downstream pipeline in parallel for all the files inside a folder given by the user... below is the sample code I wrote:-

```
def GLOBAL_RELEASE_NUMBER
def GLOBAL_BUILD_NUMBER
pipeline {

  agent { label 'centos7-itest' }
  options {
    timestamps()
    buildDiscarder(
      logRotator(
        daysToKeepStr: '100'
      )
    )
    ansiColor('xterm')
  }

  parameters {
    //some parameters
}




  environment {
    // For python3
 
  }
  stages{
        stage("setting environment") {
        environment {
            //setting up environment
        }
        steps {
            script{
               // deciding build number and release number
            }
        }
        }
        stage("Clone repo & replace variables & call my pipeline") {
                    steps {
                        withCredentials([
                            //credentials 
                        ]){
                            cleanWs()
                            deleteDir()
                            git branch: "${params.branch}", credentialsId: 'jenkins-user-key-vcs', url: 'git@github.com:some_repo/devops.git '
                            script {
                                sizingFiles = []
                                def branches = [:]
                                def counter=0

                                if (params.sizing_directory.endsWith(".yaml")) {
                                    sizingFiles.add(params.sizing_directory)
                                } else {

                                    sh(
                                        returnStdout: true,
                                        script: "find ${params.sizing_directory} -type f -name '*.yaml'"
                                    ).trim().split('\n').each { sizingFile ->
                                        sizingFiles.add(sizingFile)
                                    }

                                }
                                    for (def sizingFile in sizingFiles) {
                                        echo "Processing ${sizingFile}"

                                        sh """
                                            sed -i 's/{{[[:space:]]*user[[:space:]]*}}/${params.test_user}/g;
                                                    s/{{[[:space:]]*owner[[:space:]]*}}/my_team/g;
                                                    s/{{[[:space:]]*dept[[:space:]]*}}/team/g;
                                                    s/{{[[:space:]]*task[[:space:]]*}}/sizing/g;
                                                    s/{{[[:space:]]*SoftwareVersion[[:space:]]*}}/$GLOBAL_RELEASE_NUMBER-b$GLOBAL_BUILD_NUMBER/g' ${sizingFile}
                                            cat ${sizingFile}
                                            
                                        """

                                        branches[counter] = { 
                                            stage('myPipeline'){
                                              build job: "Myteam/myPipeline",
                                              wait: false,
                                              parameters: [ 
                                                    text(name: 'sample_yaml', value: readFile(file: sizingFile)),
                                                    string(name: 'branch', value: "${params.branch}")
                                                ]
                                            }
                                            counter+=1

                                        }

                                    }
                                parallel branches 

                            }
                    }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is when I trigger this pipeline with a folder containing 2 yaml files, I notice that the the job is triggered for first file and first completes the job and then goes to the next file to run the job for this file. I want to run all the jobs in parallel hence I gave the "wait:false" for the individual jobs. Can someone point out if what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To schedule multiple jobs in parallel you can use `collectEntries`.
Example pipeline will looks like this

```
def GLOBAL_RELEASE_NUMBER
def GLOBAL_BUILD_NUMBER
def generateStage(job) {
  return {
    stage("Terraform configure ${job}") {
      println "Processing ${job}"

      sh """
          sed -i 's/{{[[:space:]]*user[[:space:]]*}}/${params.test_user}/g;
                  s/{{[[:space:]]*owner[[:space:]]*}}/my_team/g;
                  s/{{[[:space:]]*dept[[:space:]]*}}/team/g;
                  s/{{[[:space:]]*task[[:space:]]*}}/sizing/g;
                  s/{{[[:space:]]*SoftwareVersion[[:space:]]*}}/$GLOBAL_RELEASE_NUMBER-b$GLOBAL_BUILD_NUMBER/g' ${job}
          cat ${job}
          
      """

      branches[counter] = { 
          stage('myPipeline'){
              build job: "Myteam/myPipeline",
              wait: false,
              parameters: [ 
                  text(name: 'sample_yaml', value: readFile(file: job)),
                  string(name: 'branch', value: "${params.branch}")
              ]
          }
          counter+=1

      }
    }
  }
}

pipeline {

  agent { label 'centos7-itest' }
  options {
    timestamps()
    buildDiscarder(
      logRotator(
        daysToKeepStr: '100'
      )
    )
    ansiColor('xterm')
  }

  parameters {
    //some parameters
}

  environment {
    // For python3
 
  }
  stages{
        stage("setting environment") {
        environment {
            //setting up environment
        }
        steps {
            script{
               // deciding build number and release number
            }
        }
        }
        stage("Clone repo & replace variables & call my pipeline") {
                    steps {
                        withCredentials([
                            //credentials 
                        ]){
                            cleanWs()
                            deleteDir()
                            git branch: "${params.branch}", credentialsId: 'jenkins-user-key-vcs', url: 'git@github.com:some_repo/devops.git '
                            def sizingFiles = [:]
                            def parallelStagesMap = ''

                            if (params.sizing_directory.endsWith(".yaml")) {
                                sizingFiles.add(params.sizing_directory)
                            } else {

                                sh(
                                    returnStdout: true,
                                    script: "find ${params.sizing_directory} -type f -name '*.yaml'"
                                ).trim().split('\n').each { sizingFile ->
                                    sizingFiles.add(sizingFile)
                                }

                            }

                            // sizingFiles = ['first.yaml', 'second.yaml'] <- I assume that your list looks similar to this


                            parallelStagesMap = sizingFiles.collectEntries {["${it}" : generateStage(it)]} // This will create calls to function generateStage base on amount of elements in sizingFiles
                                        
                            parallelStagesMap.failFast = false
                            parallel parallelStagesMap
                    }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some errors are coming when I run your script, first not able to access GLOBAL_RELEASE_NUMBER & GLOBAL_BUILD_NUMBER in def generateStage(job) .

Comment: You can try creating environment variable from those by adding `env.GLOBAL_RELEASE_NUMBER = GLOBAL_RELEASE_NUMBER` on stage where you are assign value to those vars. Then you should be able to access those with `${env.GLOBAL_RELEASE_NUMBER}` in `generateStage` function.